# making an App Part On the main page of SharePoint 2013 using Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, napa

I have made An App part using Napa in outlook365 which shows one URL  of my  external Application  which I have made with that the current user name is there as in pic no.1{Devlopement code successfully Made}

Now I have made another outlook account in which SharePoint will open through office 365 which will be of End-user.I need to give some rights in such a way when user Open his SharePoint in outlook 365 on Main page the above  App part will open with his name and above URL.I need to give some rights or permission so that his dashboard on login show that App part.

I don't know how to connect the above developer code with End user in such a way that App part will open in end user dashboard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines for posting. This could be improved by asking only 1 question, clearly summarizing the question in the title, improving grammar and making text more concise.

Comment: Looking at question 1, it is not clear what you are asking. I think you are looking for help adding an app part to a SharePoint site. Is that true?

Comment: I have made the app part in Office 365 SharePoint using Napa The development code is Ready. Now and I have hosted the app in app catalog in and it's available in my site content.Now What I wanted that how will I add this app on the server [on premise-->In Central Adminstrator] so that When some other person open the account he will add the app part and straight away application will view to him.

Comment: I hope my edits to your question have captured it correctly. And I hope my answer is what you're looking for. If you need to know more, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to deploying from Napa to SharePoint 2013 On Premises.

1. Publish the App and download the .app file locally
2. Upload the App to the App Catalog in SharePoint 2013 On-Premises

**Note**: Double check that the Enabled box is checked when adding the app to the App Catalog. Only when enabled is checked can users can see the app in their sites.

**Note 2**: If you don't have an App Catalog in your On-Premises SharePoint 2013 Farm, one must be created through Central Administration first.

### Reference

- [Manage the App Catalog in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234.aspx)
- [Package your add-in using Napa or Visual Studio to prepare for publishing](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-napa-or-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks Tom for Prompt reply...The app is their in site contents when I see.But when I see in some other colleague computer Its not their.Its their in Central Administration (Admin account).My Question Is How to make my application work in Intranet so that the user who is connected to active directory of SharePoint can view my application and insert the application as a App part in edit mode and than save.How to make my application work in intranet.