# Sharepoint Application in office 365 using Napa is Ready to launh. But I need my application to host in central administration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, napa

**Question 1:** I have made my application in office 365 Sharepoint using Napa.I want to host my application on central administration now to make it on premise. How do I do it please guide me.

**Question 2:** My other question is how can other user access my application add-in.Do I need to publish it in SharePoint app store so that when one open their share point they add their application and then ready to go.

**Question 3:** Is Sharepoint  app store for on-premise in central Administration and In office 365 -->Sharepoint-->app store is same.If I publish my application in Office 365 SharePoint app store would it same available in  SharePoint app store which is in central administration means on premise.

If any tutorial or link will seriously help me a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making an App Part On the main page of SharePoint 2013 using Office 365](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328050/making-an-app-part-on-the-main-page-of-sharepoint-2013-using-office-365)

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: If you used Napa tool to build an app you can open the same in VS as well. Package the same and deployed the same on your on-premise system. To verify that your app is working correctly please deploy the same on developer site (create a site collection via choosing developer template).

Answer 2: Yes you need to publish your app (having extension .app) in SharePoint via app catalog so that other users will able to access the same.

Answer 3: Both SharePoint app catalog for On-Premise app and office 365 SharePoint app store are different. For local(on-premise) user you have to publish your app on-premise and for other you have to publish it on office 365 SharePoint app store.

Below mentioned links will help you to publish your app
1. For office 365 :- Submit Office and SharePoint Add-ins and Office 365 web apps to the Office Store 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220037.aspx

2. For on-premise:- 
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging/